# How does hosting a website work when using a Backend/Database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, localhost, hosting, backend

I have hosted static sites before and here;s how it worked:

1. I have my `HTML`, `CSS`, `JavaScript` files ready
2. I upload them to a hosting site
3. and the website goes up

But now I'm starting to work on backend development with `Nodejs` and using `Mongodb` for databases.

I'm currently running my `Mongodb` database on a `localhost`.

Do I follow the same procedure as before when trying to host the site, or is there something I have to do differently?

(I figured It's different, but I don't know how to approach it)

Comment: You need a host that either already offers the DB you want as part of their offering or lets you install your db on your host.

Comment: Just for clarification, I'll need to host the DB separately, and the host would give me a URL to reference the DB in my code?

Comment: If the host offers pre-made mongodb instances, that might be the way it works.  But, it could also be that you have a hosting plan that allows you to run your own programs on the server and you install and run the DB yourself on your hosted server just like you do on localhost.  It depends upon the hosting plan.

Comment: gotcha, thank you!